# Can Cordova's device.uuid value be used to send Firebase push notification?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a wrapper app with `cordova` and using `PHP` as server backend.

I am using `cordova-plugin-fcm` to handle push notification.

Correct me if I am wrong, each device (android and ios) has own id which is used to send notification.

How can I get that id and send it to `PHP` route so that I can bind it with the logged in user and send notification?

```
//FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh( onTokenRefreshCallback(token) );
//Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first time.
FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token){
    alert( token );
});
```

In above example `token` is the id to be send to `PHP` to send notification?

Can the `device.uuid` used for sending notification?

I have already setup my `Firebase` configuration and the project has `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` in place.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can use `device.uuid` to send push notification to user device. User device need to send it to server using any kind of API endpoint so that server can know of their `uuids` and map it with particular user which can be used further to send uuid specific notifications.

Comment: @JeelVankhede any article or tutorial link to help me with this??

Comment: What exactly do you neet to know? How to send tokens to database? Or how to send notifications with php?

Comment: @MarkWalczak if I can use `uuid` to send notification and how? I know how to send token to database.

Comment: @MarkWalczak if I use `uuid` to send notification, how do I handle the notification in app?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging targets its messages at a specific app on a specific device. Each specific app install is identified by Firebase's Instance ID, also referred to as a device registration token, or an FCM token.

The Firebase documentation on [accessing the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) says this about it:

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. If you want to target single devices or create device groups, you'll need to access this token by extending `FirebaseMessagingService` and overriding `onNewToken`.

From a quick read through the Cordova [documentation on device.uuid](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/), this seems to merely identify the device, and not the app on the device. Since FCM messages are delivered **to a specific app** on each device, it seems unlikely you can use the UUID of the device as a replacement.

Even if the UUID is unique for each app on each device, it won't be a drop-in replacement, as FCM only works with its own registration tokens. At the very least you'll need to keep a mapping of the `device.uuid` values to their corresponding FCM token.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but surely there is an alternative to FCM, what if Google decides to start charging for push notifications.